# How to Add table in SQliteDatabase

Tags: android-sqlite

I want to add a table in database and want to add a column and save information and retrieve it on another button clicked, if table already exists it would just insert information  following is the code that is used by me but giving error.

```
Button insert_info=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
insert_info.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        try
        {
            final EditText txt_field1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String Per_Name=txt_field1.getText().toString();

            db=openOrCreateDatabase("sez.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
            String Query_createTable="CREATE TABLE  sezInformation(Name VARCHAR(100))";
            String Query_insert="insert into sezInformation(Name) values("+Per_Name+")";
            db.execSQL(Query_insert);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(WelomePerson.this, "ERROR"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Whenever I enter the value means `khan` or any other in layout `Edittext` field and click on button it shows

```
No such column :khan while insert into sezInformation (Name) values(khan)
```

Please also tell me how to retrieve the same saved data in a textview.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: whenever i enter the value means "khan" or any other in layout Edittext field and click on button it shows       no such column :khan while insert into sezInformation (Name) values(khan)

Comment: please tell me also how to retrieve the same saved data in a textview

Comment: I edited your question accordingly to keep everything in one place (so that potential helpers don't have to look through your comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` instead of `CREATE TABLE`.
Also be sure to use 2 distinct `execSQL()` commands (one to create the table and one to insert), or it won't work, since **you can't execute multiple commands at once**.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, string literals should be in `'single quotes'`. Otherwise they are taken as identifiers such as column names.

Even better, use parameters:

```
db.execSQL("insert into sezInformation(Name) values(?)",
    new Object[] { Per_Name });
```